# unserialize(): Error at offset 10 of 672 bytes

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I'm building a codeigniter app with sql server.

I started the app with MySQL and it worked fine but then when I merged my table to sql server I got this error :

> Message: unserialize(): Error at offset 10 of 672 bytes
>
> Filename: core/MY_Controller.php
>
> Line Number: 3

Here's my controller.php

```
 public function __construct() 
{
    parent::__construct();

    $group_data = array();
    if(empty($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))) {
        $session_data = array('logged_in' => FALSE);
        $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
    }
    else {
        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
        $this->load->model('model_groups');
        $group_data = $this->model_groups->getUserGroupByUserId($user_id);
        
        $this->data['user_permission'] = unserialize($group_data['permission']);

        $this->permission = unserialize($group_data['permission']);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.jackreichert.com/2014/02/handling-a-php-unserialize-offset-error/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used the preg_replace_callback function and it worked fine for me :

```
   $group_data['permission']=preg_replace_callback('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!', 
            function($match) {
             return ($match[1] == strlen($match[2])) ? $match[0] : 's:' . strlen($match[2]) . ':"' . $match[2] . '";';},
             $error_serialized_data);
```

Comment: your error says that method in controller needs 1 parameter, you called it as `Request $request`, erase it. This is the solution of your question.